# Regular expressions not working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to filter on file uploader. It works fine in FireFox but in Google Chrome it always shows invalid file although file is valid .

```
function validate() {
    var uploadcontrol = document.getElementById('<%=fileupload.ClientID%>').value;

    //Regular Expression for fileupload control.
    //var reg = /^(([a-zA-Z])|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.jpg|.jpeg|.jpe|.gif|.bmp|.png|.JPG|.JPEG|.JPE|.GIF|.BMP|.PNG)$/;
    var reg = /^(([0-9a-zA-Z\^\&\'\@\{\}\[\]\,\$\=\!\-\#\(\)\%\+\~\_ ]))+(.jpg|.jpeg|.jpe|.gif|.bmp|.png|.JPG|.JPEG|.JPE|.GIF|.BMP|.PNG|.dds|.psd|.pspimage|.tga|.thm|.tif|.tiff|.yuv)$/;

    if (uploadcontrol.length > 0) {
        //Checks with the control value.
        if (reg.test(uploadcontrol)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            //If the condition not satisfied shows error message.
            alert("Only Images are allowed!");
            return false;
        }
    }
} //End of function validate.
```

Comment: Any reason why you're doing a case sensitive test? You include `a-zA-Z` at the beginning, but some of the file extensions are only allowing lowercase. If you add an `i` flag to the regex does it fix the problem? As in: `var reg = /yourregexhere/i;` (This would also simplify the pattern since you wouldn't need to specify both `.jpg` and `.JPG`, etc.)

Comment: Which filename does this regex fail on? Can you give an example?

Comment: The dot `.` before the file extensions will need to be escaped, and all the chars in that character class other than `\]-` do not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very strange regex you have there. Try this one

```
var reg = /^[^\\//]+\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|gif|bmp|png|dds|psd|pspimage|tga|thm|tif|tiff|yuv)$/i;
```

This one works for me with various file names in chrome.

The i modifier in the end will ignore casing, and the name matching is a bit more generous like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your test does seem to be working in chrome, [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/redders6600/yj78v/1/).

As such I think you need to debug the value of `uploadcontrol` in chrome and firefox to see how they differ, then tune your regex.

Comment: The regex "works" in Chrome in the sense that Chrome correctly interprets the regex exactly as given. But that regex isn't suitable for the OP's situation unless he specifically wants to allow upper and lower case `jpg` but only lower case `tif`...

Comment: Agreed the regex is dodgy. I merely meant it works in Chrome in the same way that the OP it stated it works in FireFox.